# Developing android app for both Google play and Amazon Store

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, amazon-appstore

I am a newbie in android app development. After great amount of efforts , I developed an android app for Amazon App Store. My app included in-app purchase feature. However, the app got rejected from Amazon App store as it did not work on Samsung galaxy S2. What can I do so that my app runs on all devices with the in-app purchase for both Amazon and Google Playstore? Is there any pre-built Library for this purpose? any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

OpenIAB - Open In-App Billing is an in app billing library which helps you integrate many stores in your app from one library. here is their intro:

> Uploading Android apps to all the existing Android appstores is a painful process and the AppDF project was designed to make it easier. But what is even more difficult for developers is supporting different in-purchase APIs of different appstores. There are five different In-App Purchase APIs already and this number is increasing. We are going to create an open-source library that will wrap appstore in-app purchase APIs of all the stores and provide an easy way for the developers to develop their apps/games in such a way that one APK will work in all the stores and automatically use the right in-app purchase API under each store. We will also develop an open in-app billing API that stores could implement to support all the built APK files using this library.

Here is [openIAB's github repository](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB). Not only openIAB supports Google Play and amazon but it supports yandex, samsung apps and more...

**UPDATE:**
In order to automatically test your app against many device configurations you may use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).There are many tutorials online and here is [one example tutorial](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/android-and-jenkins-continuous) for you from dzone.

Comment: The tutorial link not working :( Have you tried implementing this? (just asking)

Comment: I have already downloaded jenkins and installed and its working. Its reccomended by many devs. However I admit that it might be overkill for a one man projects. I tested OpenIAB. Its API is very similar to google's billinghelper API. I haven't yet submitted my apps to Google or Amazon but I can confirm that their API is working in my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RoboBilling which supports both Amazon and Google.

https://github.com/christopherperry/RoboBillingLibrary

It is a custom build Java library that intends to be a "pre-built Library for this purpose."

That said, I will note that my own games use custom stores for each platform, coded to support the latest SDK and IAB libraries for each vendor. It is expensive to maintain but it provides consistent results.